# URL Rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my htacces file content. Its not working. Please help me guys...

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^jeans-shirt/?$ /index.php?index/indexproducts/jeans-shirt/c695b64e4b38d8004f7c9b970ecbd104 [QSA,NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 404.html
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Its not showing the page.

Comment: Which page is now showing, provide full URL? Are .htaccess and mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

</IfModule>
```